# Magento 1.x popup confirmation modal in admin panel

Tags: admin-panel, popup, modal-popup, alert, confirmation

I'm wondering if there's any way to set up a popup confirmation message or an alert message under certain settings on my products in back-end panel. Thanks a lot

Comment: you should add magento1 tag to get proper audience .